# como hacer que el formato "DD/MM/YYYY" se vea reflejado en mi archivo.csv en vez del formato "YYYY-MM-DD"

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

Aquí les paso las dos funciones de mi código que considero importantes para resolver el problema:

```
def crear_tarea(self):
    crear_titulo = input("ingrese un titulo a su tarea: ")
    crear_descripcion = input("ingrese una descripcion a su tarea: \n")
    crear_fecha = input("ingrese una fecha de creación a su tarea: ")
    convertir_a_fecha = pd.to_datetime(crear_fecha, format="%d/%m/%Y", dayfirst=True)
    crear_fecha_vencimiento = input("ingrese una fecha de vencimiento a su tarea: ")
    convertir_a_fecha_vencimiento = pd.to_datetime(crear_fecha_vencimiento,  format="%d/%m/%Y", dayfirst=True)
    nueva_tarea = Tarea(crear_titulo, crear_descripcion, convertir_a_fecha, convertir_a_fecha_vencimiento)
    self.tareas.append(nueva_tarea)
    self.guardar_tarea(nueva_tarea)

def guardar_tarea(self, tarea_a_guardar):
        df_aux = pd.DataFrame({
            "titulo" : [tarea_a_guardar.titulo],
            "descripción" : [tarea_a_guardar.descripcion],
            "fecha de creación" : [tarea_a_guardar.fecha_creacion],
            "fecha de vencimiento" : [tarea_a_guardar.fecha_vencimiento],
            "completada" : [tarea_a_guardar.completada]
        })

        df_aux.to_csv("registro_tareas.csv", mode = "a", header = False, index = False)
```

A pesar de que uso `format="%d/%m/%Y"` y `dayfirst=True` en `pd.to_datetime` en mí `archivo.csv`, se ven las fechas con el formato por defecto "YYYY-MM-DD", como se puede observar:

```
titulo,descripción,fecha de creación,fecha de vencimiento,completada

titulo,descripcion,2023-12-26,2024-12-26,False
```

Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para que en mí `archivo.csv` las fechas estén en el formato "DD/MM/YYYY".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más directo:

```
df_aux.to_csv(nombre_archivo, date_format ='%d/%m/%Y')
```